# Data type mismatch when using form control as criteria

Tags: ms-access

I have a form in MS Access that has an unbound control named `boxReferenceMonthGtis` that **correctly** displays a date.

This control *Control Source* property is `=[GTIS_subform].[Form]![ReferenceMonth]` which is a field of type `Date/Time` in a subform.

When I try to use this control in a query in the **SELECT** clause it shows this gibberish �䃤.

After reading [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_access-mso_winother-mso_2007/unbound-short-date-from-form-field-displays-in/056b59d9-1379-4068-a8ed-376b0a384cc0?messageId=0297e6cf-9ac1-45f6-bc65-cc4dd9c0dd2c) I added `PARAMETERS [Forms]![Conciliacao]![boxReferenceMonthGtis] DateTime` to my SQL, and the **SELECT** statement started showing the correct value.

**However**, If I try to use my control as a criteria to filter another field like:

```
WHERE DateSerial(Year([Departure]),Month([Departure]),1)=[Forms]![Conciliacao]![boxReferenceMonthGtis]
```

I'm prompted with

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

What is weird is that if I filter the field `[Departure]` like:

```
WHERE ShippingTrack.Departure=[Forms]![Conciliacao]![boxReferenceMonthGtis]
```

There is no error!

#### What else I have tried without success

Same error (Data type mismatch)

```
WHERE CDate(DateSerial(Year([Departure]),Month([Departure]),1)=[Forms]![Conciliacao]![boxReferenceMonthGtis]

WHERE CDate(DateSerial(Year([Departure]),Month([Departure]),1)=CDate([Forms]![Conciliacao]![boxReferenceMonthGtis]

WHERE CVDate(DateSerial(Year([Departure]),Month([Departure]),1)=CVDate([Forms]![Conciliacao]![boxReferenceMonthGtis]
```

**Does anybody knows how to make this work?**

What is even weirder is that I have another query in the same database that I can use `WHERE DateSerial(Year([Departure]),Month([Departure]),1)=[Forms]![Conciliacao]![boxReferenceMonthGtis]` without any issue!

Comment: It could be that some records have _Null_ for Departure.

Comment: It was it! Post it as an answer so I can mark as answered.

Comment: Great! And done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK:

It could be that some records have *Null* for Departure.